# Confusion with mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

I am unfamiliar with the mysqli_fetch_array and can't seem to figure this out. I have the following code:

```
function select_fetch_row ($arg1, $arg2) {
    $con = new mysqli(/* ... */);
    $query = "SELECT $arg1 FROM $arg2";
    $select = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select, MYSQLI_NUM)){
        echo $row[0];
    }

}

select_fetch_row(/* parameters*/);
```

However I'm not understanding what it's supposed to be doing. I was expecting to obtain an array where each key would correspond to a row in my table, but when I output my code, rather than just having the value of the first row (`$row[0]`) echoed, all the values of the column get echoed. Can someone shed some light on how this function really works?

Comment: Do you send any parameters to your function while calling? doesn't seem to be the case. Those parameters are required to build that query properly

Comment: Please, **do not** use string concatenation to compose queries. Use the [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I forgot to add them in the example above, but in my code I did. Will edit above, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @tadman: how would you put the dynamic table name into the query with that and without concatenation? How would you vary the query `WHERE` criterias dynamically without concatenation?

Comment: `mysqli` isn't the best system for this, PDO offers some more flexibility, but yeah, table and column names are always trouble. You should be white-listing what those are to avoid all kinds of hurt if you're putting in arbitrary user data. At the very least these should be given correct names and escaping: `SELECT \`$column\` FROM \`$table\`` would make it a lot more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select, MYSQLI_NUM)){
        echo $row[0];
    }
```

You're fetching the rows one by one, *not* in a single array. So each $row variable has a single row from your table, with each key containing a column value. So when you echo $row[0], you're showing the first column of the row you've returned.

If you change the parameter MYSQLI_NUM to MYSQLI_ASSOC, you'll have a better idea of what's happening (the array keys will contain the column names instead of integers).

If you want to fetch all the rows in one go, you can use mysqli_fetch_all instead, which will give you one big array, containing one row per key.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php